# Viewpager with fragment pager adapter and Fragment - retainInstanceState recreates fragment on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation, fragmentpageradapter

When I use retainInstanceState(true) in fragment and use it with a FragmentPagerAdapter, the fragment is recreated. Which is not expected behaviour. What is a potential work around

I found [a blog post](http://www.bernie-eng.com/blog/2013/01/23/retaining-fragments-in-viewpagers/) which gives a solution not to use retainInstanceState which is not possible in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out viewpager retains fragments and tries to find fragment with that id.

First thing to do in Fragment's onCreate:

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

In activity with tabs, Make sure you handle `onSaveInstanceState` correctly

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(bundle){
   super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

Even **without** saving viewpager id or reference to fragment as suggested in similar questions, the same fragment is reattached on orientation change